Finsler norm exercise help
Hello i am new at the course of Finsler geometry and i need some help because i have an exercise that sound like this:
On $$R^2 $$ with the global coordinates (u,v) we have the function:
$$F:R^2->R, F(u,v)=u^{1/2}(u^2+bv^2)^{1/4}$$ determine the values of b in R such that F define a Finsler norm on R^2 , for the find b determine: indicator $$I={(u,v) in R^2|F(u,v)=1}$$, the metric tensor, the Cartan tensor, fundamental inequality (Cauchy-Schwartz) and the triangle inequality. I can't do anithing for this exercise  and don't know how to start, please help!
